Повторный вызов запроса
Иногда при отладке, наблюдаю такое. Допустим, есть контроллер с  ендпойнтом, он вызывает какой-то сервис, сервис вызывает какой-то репозиторий или другой сервис. Где-то там я ставлю breakpoint. Прихожу на breakpoint. Иду по шагам, по строчкам. И если в какой-то строке вдруг бросается исключение (но иногда и без исключения!) ВНЕЗАПНО я оказываюсь опять на брекпойнте, который уже проходил. И стек вроде такой же - в нем есть и контроллер с ендпойнтом, и миддлвари. Но поток другой.
То есть код реально под отладчиком исполняется два раза (иногда и три), если вставить отладочную печать, то в Output можно увидеть несколько напечатанных строк.
Почему так? Циклов там нет, какого-то Retry-middleware тоже нет. Запрос делаю напрямую из строки браузера, клиентский JS не участвует (да и запрос во вкладке Network в Devtools виден только один). Воспроизводится не каждый раз и только под отладчиком.
Что это?

Интересный вопрос. Я такое когда наблюдал обычно списывал на то, что ещё один запрос пришёл и стал обрабатываться, но, видимо, ситуация интереснее. Подождём знатоков таких тонкостей.

Под подозрением у меня были:

параметр CancellationToken в контроллере, который может сработать, если долго висишь в отладке: браузер перестает ждать запрос по таймауту и токен срабатывает. Убрал, не помогло.
сам браузер (Яндекс.Браузер). Быть может, он просто дублирует запросы втихаря? Пока не проверял.

